# drupal 7 , multiple FROM tables, need a very sample example

Tags: drupal-7

Someone can give me an example where there is a multiple 'FROM' table ?

I don't understand corectly the documentation (thanks my bad english lvl -_-).
I would like use a query like : 
SELECT a.one a.two b.one FROM {table1} a, {table2} b WHERE a.one = b.one

thx =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join:
http://drupal.org/node/1848348

```
<?php
$query = db_select('table1', 'a');
$query->join('table2', 'b', 'a.one = b.one');
$query->fields('a', array('one', 'two'));
$query->fields('b', array('one'));
$result = $query->execute();
?>
```

Here is asked and answered:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27723/drupal-7-join-two-tables

More about dynamic queries
http://drupal.org/node/310075